# How to get property info from ODataPrimitiveSerializer

Tags: c#, odata

I am using custom ODataPrimitiveTypeSerializer:

```
    public class PrimitiveSerializer : ODataPrimitiveSerializer
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Rewriting value
        /// </summary>
        public override ODataPrimitiveValue CreateODataPrimitiveValue(object graph, IEdmPrimitiveTypeReference primitiveType, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
        {
            if (graph is string stringValue && primitiveType is EdmStringTypeReference typeReference)
            {
                graph = GetCalculatedValue(stringValue);
            }
            var value = base.CreateODataPrimitiveValue(graph, primitiveType, writeContext);

            return value;
        }
}
```

I want to rewrite value based on entity and propertyInfo. For example, if entity name is Encrypted I want to decrypt some properties. But I couldn't find entity or property info from PrimitiveSerializer. Is there any way to get entity type and proeprtyinfo ?

Comment: Use `ODataResourceSerializer` instead, you may need to handle this at the resource level, however it still wont give you a reference to the data model properties, only the EdmModel properties of the resource being serialized, which might be enough, otherwise you will have to map back manually.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller, I tried, but I couldn't. Can you provide some code examples?